# How can I add some custom polyfill in my gatsby application?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering, polyfills, css-variables

So, I want to add polyfill for CSS variables in my gatsby application and I got [this](https://codepen.io/aaronbarker/pen/MeaRmL?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=ada3f4dda337d1666d885d75668e8e9097fccfaf-1592569884-0-Abr6sX7EzmDn7FNUhaVLicjhee_UuK2IdBXzlO9N74q13cvxMjRAUV2-j-NZ1QlEAZeGY9Mor78gSn6O8ZdHe9nxPv_XCZUPZF-nRWH2JXodQDTJ0JElmjcNUe31REHn50CSmiQG6V0VZdlcuCWjDp0E3TUK2b0HZTu8AFBClprL3BS2K6637bK83TilXxnh47eIP4QNKXjdjYlEVhftu7bjZjjHW1wTLSd2eY5VklNfR3q6W9aOdYmfx_0naQAxoQa7JeM8jIPhqq9GWy5v-gziceNsuo6DGccGKGHIUd3JLtJMmavFnfnA42YlKGw2ZzF5bO4W-dG8sy2DTdB2kqfRRF3AVmHO3SCl091dzC6y). So, how can I now add this file to the project as polyfill.

PS: Adding HTML for polyfill just beacasue its not letting me post the codepen link without code.

```
  <h1>CSS Variables Polyfill</h1>
  <p>This is now managed (and available for PRs) at <a href="https://github.com/aaronbarker/css-variables-polyfill">https://github.com/aaronbarker/css-variables-polyfill</a>.</p>
  <p>
    This is an attempt at a very basic <a href="https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/">CSS variables (custom properties)</a> polyfil. In reality this is more of a <em>partial</em> polyfill as it will not cover variables inside of variables, DOM scoping or anything else "fancy". Just taking variables declared anywhere in the CSS and
    then re-parsing the CSS for var() statements and replacing them in browsers that don't natively support CSS variables.
  </p>
  <p>According to <a href="http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables">caniuse.com</a>, of current browsers only IE, Edge and Opera Mini do not support CSS variables. This polyfil appears to work on all three really well. I don't see why this wouldn't work on older browsers as well, but I haven't been able to test it on them yet.</p>

  <p>As far as we can tell your browser <span class="supports">does <span class="no">not</span> support</span> native CSS variables. <span class="showforpolyfill">That means if you see green tests results below, it is thanks to the polyfill :).</span> <span class="hideforpolyfill">All the green test results below are actually native CSS Variable support.  Good job using a good browser :)</span></p>

  <h3>Does this work on externally CSS files?</h3>
  <p>Yes!</p>
  <h3>Even ones loaded from another domain?</h3>
  <p>To go across domain, CSS needs to be served up with <code>Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*</code> headers.</p>

</div>
<a href="#d" class="hide-docs">Toggle documentation</a> (for Opera Mini vs Codepen issue)
<style>
  :root {
    --newcolor: #0f0;
  }

  .inlineoverlink {
    color: var(--success2);
  }
</style>
<h2>Tests</h2>
<p>On mosts tests (unless otherwise noted) success will be green text. We start with a <code>color:red;</code> and then override it with a <code>color:var(--success);</code> (or similar) which is green.</p>
<ul>
  <li><span class="samename">declare same variable over and over</span></li>
  <li><span class="demo1">no whitespace on var() calls</span></li>
  <li><span class="demo2">whitespace on var() calls</span></li>
  <li><span class="demo3">Multiple variables in same call. orange means first var worked, green var worked</span></li>
  <li><span class="inlineoverlink">orange if link won, green if style after link won</span></li>
  <li><span class="lower">--foo: lowercase foo</span></li>
  <li><span class="upper">--FOO: uppercase FOO</span></li>
  <li><span class="fallback">uses fallback <code>--var(--wrongname, green)</code></span></li>
  <li><span class="demo-import">css declared in an <code>@import</code></span> - not polyfilled yet. <a href="https://gist.github.com/stramel/91d05253f801f771da38b3bc7d3c765f#gistcomment-2258818">Identfied with a suggested fix</a>, but will require a bit of a re-write (to use document.styleSheets), so haven't done it yet.</li>
</ul>


<h2>Tests on external, cross-domain file</h2>
<div class="documentation">
  <p><strong>Edge</strong> appears to be working well on Edge 13. Edge 12 was having some problems.</p>
  <p><strong>Opera mini</strong> seems to work well too. This demo fails because not all the page is displayed, but I think that is a codepen issue, not a polyfill issue.  When the upper documentation is removed, all tests display well.</p>
  <p><strong>IE 11</strong> seems to do fine.</p>
</div>

<ul>
  <li><span class="demo4">Gets stuff from external .css file. Should start red and change to green on LINK load. border proves the CSS loaded, missing colors means script didn't get parsed and reinserted</span></li>
  <li><span class="externalcolor">--externalcolor: should start red and change to green on LINK load</span></li>
  <li><span class="externalfallback">uses fallback. should be green</span></li>
</ul>

<p>Another set of text under the test for Opera Mini testing.</p  >
```

Comment: I added my custom polyfills in gatsby-browser.js and it works